# Read json web service spring mvc

Tags: java, json, web-services, jquery-mobile, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc Web service like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")

public class helloWs {
   @RequestMapping(value= "/getObj",  method = RequestMethod.GET)

public
@ResponseBody
User prueba(@RequestBody User user) {

    user.setEmail("sample_email@sample.com");
    user.setName("sample_name");
    user.setDeleted(true);

    return user;
}
}
```

The jquery call to this Web service is:

```
function hellowsfunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"http://localhost:8080/ehCS-ui/rest/hello/getUser",

        dataType: "json",

        success: function(msg) {
        $('#lblResult').html('<p> Name: ' + msg.name + '</p>');
         $('#lblResult').append('<p>email : ' + msg.email+ '</p>');
         $('#lblResult').append('<p> deleted: ' + msg.setDeleted+ '</p>');
            alert('Success: ' + response);



     },
      error: function (e) { 
            $("#lblResult").removeClass("loading");
            alert('failed:'+e);
            console.log(e);
             }
     });

    }
```

And the result should be in a div like this.

```
 <div id ="lblResult" style="color:blue;">result   here</div>
```

But my javascript console show me this error all the time, and I don't know what is wrong.

```
Error. [object Object]
```

The web service is ok, but it seems that Jquery doesn't read the json obectj:
This is a user object that web service returns on the bowser.

```
{"version":null,"deleted":true,"insertDate":null,"updateDate":null,"owner":null,"userId":null,"name":"sample_name","surname1":null,"surname2":null,"login":null,"collegiateNumber":null,"nif":null,"email":"sample_email@sample.com","surname2Required":null,"telefonNumber":null,"birthDate":null,"inactive":false,"inactiveReason":null,"inactiveDate":null,"position":null,"professionals":null,"applications":null,"areas":null,"sexType":null,"locale":null,"password":null,"id":null}
```

Please help me. thanks a lot

Comment: What happens when you load this: http://localhost:8080/ehCS-ui/rest/hello/getUser Directly in your browser.

Comment: the service shows the json user::  {"version":null,"deleted":true,"insertDate":null,"updateDate":null,"owner":null,"userId":null,"name":"sample_name","surname1":null,"surname2":null,"login":null,"collegiateNumber":null,"nif":null,"email":"sample_email@sample.com","surname2Required":null,"telefonNumber":null,"birthDate":null,"inactive":false,"inactiveReason":null,"inactiveDate":null,"position":null,"professionals":null,"applications":null,"areas":null,"sexType":null,"locale":null,"password":null,"id":null}

Comment: Sorry I see that in the q now. Are you running both on localhost?

Comment: Yes, both in localhost

Comment: Is the response mime type of the web service response "application/json"?

Comment: I dont understand your question. I wrote the @ResponseBody  and the  spring mvc anotation for convert the response in a json data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change:

```
$('#lblResult').append('<p> deleted: ' + msg.setDeleted+ '</p>');
```

to

```
$('#lblResult').append('<p> deleted: ' + msg.deleted+ '</p>');
```

Comment: oh yes, it is a mistake but it doesn't solve my problem. The reponse is wrong yet. #lblResult can be a div or it should be a <ul> list?

Comment: It looks like there is an error occurring somewhere in either the `success` or the `error` function prior to any `alert` messages getting executed. I would recommend debugging the error getting output in the console using Firebug or something similar.

Comment: I've tried it with the javascript debugger in chrome, and the console don't show wich error ocurrs. It only shows statusText= error, and responseText = "", 
 But , if I changed data to jsonp, the response is Ok, Status 200,  but jquery cant read the data.